# Detecting folder content in URL not showing .php or .html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

How can you make your URL to be visible in this format? but still have both value available.

for example when my customer click on link to "about" page not take them to index.php of the folder but automatically detect the .php or .html of the folder and show it in this format in URL.

```
http://www.example.com/about/
```

Not like this:

```
http://www.example.com/about/index.php
```

is there a way to do it with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we use the DirectoryIndex s.t.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

in .htaccess or httpd.conf.

Comment: Does this even work, even if the file is not called index.php? would it work on about.php?